# question about idempotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let me assume that $M$ is an idempotent matrix ($M^2=M$) and $I-M$ is not zero ($I$ is identity matrix with the same dim as $M$).

If I multiply $I-M$ by $M$, $M-M^2=M-M=0$.

How could it be possible? multiplication with non-zero matrices yields zero matrix.
Is there any one to help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This means that the rows of $M$ are orthogonal to the columns of $I-M$.

A geometric interpretation of this is the following: Consider an orthogonal projection, i.e. $P$ with $P=P^2$ and $P=P^*$.

Then $P$ is a projection onto $\operatorname{ran} P$, and $Q=I-P$ is a projection onto $(\operatorname{ran} P)^\perp$.

The property of $PQ=0$ means that for any $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ $Px$ and $Qy$ are orthogonal to each other, and we can not only write $x=Px+Qx$ but even $$x = Px \oplus Qx = Px \oplus (I-P)x$$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\begin {pmatrix} 0&-1\\0&0\end {pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&0\end {pmatrix}$. What is $AB$? Yes, it is possible.

Comment: AB is definitely zero! thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen.
Consider for instance the matrix
$$M = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right].$$

Then you can easily see that $(I - M)M = 0$ even thought $I - M \ne 0$ and $M \ne 0$. Remember that the set of the square matrices endowed with the sum and product is just a ring, not a field. (Note that $M$ and $I-M$ are not invertible!).

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer!
Could you explain to me about the physical concepts of ring and field?

Comment: As i'm not a mathematician, really hard for me to get it :-(

Comment: Mmmh I don't know physical interpretation of rings and fields. They are just abstract algebraic structures and I suggest you to take a look to their definitions in Wikipedia. :) But essentially every field is a ring, but not every ring is a field (as in the case of the square matrices).